# Apache Hadoop Windows 10 - Datanode, Resource Manager and Yarn immediately shutdown on startup

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, disk, datanode

I have followed a tutorial to setup Apache Hadoop for Windows, which can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLVWrGGqGJU). I am now having an issue with the Datanode, Resource Manager, and Yarn cmd windows showing that all 3 shutdown seconds after opening, with only the Namenode continuing to run. Here is the process I have tried so far:

1. run CMD as admin
2. use command `start-all.cmd` (this opens the Namenode, Datanode, Yarn, and Resourcemanager cmd windows)
3. Datanode, Yarn, and Resource manager all give shutdown messages almost immediately after they start

`SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down ResourceManager at thood-alienware/...`

`SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NodeManager at thood-alienware/...`

`SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at thood-alienware/...`

4. Interestingly enough, only the Datanode window gives an error as a reason for shutting down:

`2019-03-26 00:07:03,382 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0`

I know that I can edit the amount of tolerated failures, but I'd like to actually fix whatever is causing this disk failure. When I open the datanode directory, it's an empty folder, however my namenode directory has files present within that were created from the `start-all.cmd'. Has anyone worked with Hadoop on Windows before? I'm totally at a loss for where to go from here because most online help is for Linux systems.

Answer (score 1):

Did you get the following bin files in HADOOP directory

https://github.com/s911415/apache-hadoop-3.1.0-winutils